# how to convert negative integer value to hex in python

Tags: python, integer, hex, negative-number

I use python 2.6

```
>>> hex(-199703103)
'-0xbe73a3f'

>>> hex(199703103)
'0xbe73a3f'
```

Positive and negative value are the same?

When I use calc, the value is `FFFFFFFFF418C5C1`.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Python's integers can grow arbitrarily large. In order to compute the raw [two's-complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) the way you want it, you would need to specify the desired bit width. Your example shows `-199703103` in 64-bit two's complement, but it just as well could have been 32-bit or 128-bit, resulting in a different number of `0xf`'s at the start.

`hex()` doesn't do that. I suggest the following as an alternative:

```
def tohex(val, nbits):
  return hex((val + (1 << nbits)) % (1 << nbits))

print tohex(-199703103, 64)
print tohex(199703103, 64)
```

This prints out:

```
0xfffffffff418c5c1L
0xbe73a3fL
```

Comment: Could you please explain what is going on when you're adding `(1<<64)`? Why does that need to be done?

Comment: @jathanism, the value `(1<<64)` is one larger than will fit in a 64-bit integer. Adding it to a negative number will turn it positive, as long as the negative number fits in 64 bits. If the original number was positive, the `%` will undo the effect of the addition.

Comment: I believe there is a bug in this implementation: tohex(-129,8) returns 0x7f, which is impossible since a 8-bit signed integer can only store numbers from (-1)* (2 ^7)= -128 to 2^7 - 1 = 127. Therefore the function should check if val is within this range before returns, if it is not, raise an exception (or something). This can make the code more robust, i think :)

Answer (score 22):

Because Python integers are arbitrarily large, you have to mask the values to limit conversion to the number of bits you want for your 2s complement representation.

```
>>> hex(-199703103 & (2**32-1)) # 32-bit
'0xf418c5c1L'
>>> hex(-199703103 & (2**64-1)) # 64-bit
'0xfffffffff418c5c1L'
```

Python displays the simple case of `hex(-199703103)` as a negative hex value (`-0xbe73a3f`) because the 2s complement representation would have an infinite number of Fs in front of it for an arbitrary precision number.  The mask value (2**32-1 == 0xFFFFFFFF) limits this:

```
FFF...FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF418c5c1
&                             FFFFFFFF
--------------------------------------
                              F418c5c1
```

Comment: Although concise, isn't the raising to a power costly compared with bit manipulation?

Comment: @swdev, `py -m timeit "2**32-1"` -> 0.0235 usec per loop,
`py -m timeit "2<<32-1"` -> 0.0235 usec per loop.  Don't assume.  Always measure if you care :)  Most likely the Python byte compiler generates the same load constant.

Comment: oops, make that `(1<<32)-1`...but you get the idea...Also easier to make mistakes.  And I checked with the `dis` module and Python just generates a constant.

Comment: Also you could, inlieu of `2**32-1` just use the constant `0xFFFFFFFF` for 32-bit and `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` for 64-bit if you are that concerned about timing. Or `mask_32bit=(2**32-1)` so that you don't have to do the calculation each time, just once.

Comment: @busfault per comment above speed is no different.  Python calculates the constant once when generating byte code.  No need to "optimize".

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thanks I didn't realize that (obviously) :-)

Answer (score 2):

Adding to [Marks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7825412/806690), if you want a different output format, use

```
'{:X}'.format(-199703103 & (2**32-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who want leading zeros for positive numbers, try this:

```
val = 42
nbits = 16
'{:04X}'.format(val & ((1 << nbits)-1))
```

[image]

Thanks @tm1, for the inspiration!

Comment: ```'{:0{}X}'.format(val & ((1 << nbits)-1), int((nbits+3)/4))``` will set the width correct.