# Blowfish decryption in python of string encoded by javax.crypto

Tags: java, python, encryption, pycrypto, javax.crypto

Using the code found at https://raw.github.com/usefulfor/usefulfor/master/security/JBoss.java, I did thefollowing:

```
bash-3.2$ java -cp . JBoss -e testpython
-27038292d345798947e2852756afcf0a
bash-3.2$ java -cp . JBoss -d -27038292d345798947e2852756afcf0a
testpython
```

However, I can't for the life of me, figure out how to decrypt the string '27038292d345798947e2852756afcf0a' using pycrypto in python.  My understanding is that the Java code is using Blowfish, and the phrase 'jaas is the way' as the key for the cipher.  But I can't make any sense of how to do this in python.  The following results in mostly unprintable garbage:

```
import Crypto
from Crypto.Cipher import Blowfish
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode

bs        = Blowfish.block_size
key       = 'jaas is the way'
plaintext = b'27038292d345798947e2852756afcf0a'
iv        = '\0' * 8

c1 = Blowfish.new(key, Blowfish.MODE_ECB)
c2 = Blowfish.new(key, Blowfish.MODE_CBC, iv)
c3 = Blowfish.new(key, Blowfish.MODE_CFB, iv)
c4 = Blowfish.new(key, Blowfish.MODE_OFB, iv)

msg1 = c1.decrypt(plaintext)
msg2 = c2.decrypt(plaintext)
msg3 = c3.decrypt(plaintext)
msg4 = c4.decrypt(plaintext)

print "msg1 = %s\n" % msg1
print "msg2 = %s\n" % msg2 
print "msg3 = %s\n" % msg3 
print "msg4 = %s\n" % msg4
```

What am I missing ?

thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Make sure you mark an answer as accepted with the check box next to an answer.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, that Java example code is very bad. It outputs the ciphertext as an integer, whereas ciphertext should remain a binary string. The reason is that an integer can be represented in an infinite number of binary encodings. For instance, the number one can be '0x01' (1 byte), '0x0001' (2 bytes), and so forth. When you are dealing with cryptographic functions, you must be extremely precise with the representation.

Additionally, the example uses the default values of the `javax.crypto` API, which are not described anywhere. So it is really trial and error.

For the solution, you must know [how to convert negative integers to hex strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822956/how-to-convert-negative-integer-value-to-hex-in-python). In this case, you don't need a hex string, but its byte representation. The concept is the same though. I use PyCrypto's `long_to_bytes` to convert a positive integer (of arbitrary length) to a byte string.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import Blowfish
from Crypto.Util.number import long_to_bytes

def tobytestring(val, nbits):
    """Convert an integer (val, even negative) to its byte string representation.
    Parameter nbits is the length of the desired byte string (in bits).
    """
    return long_to_bytes((val + (1 << nbits)) % (1 << nbits), nbits/8)

key = b'jaas is the way'
c1  = Blowfish.new(key, Blowfish.MODE_ECB)

fromjava = b"-27038292d345798947e2852756afcf0a"
# We don't know the real length of the ciphertext, assume it is 16 bytes
ciphertext = tobytestring(int(fromjava, 16), 16*8)
print c1.decrypt(ciphertext)
```

The output is:

```
'testpython\x06\x06\x06\x06\x06\x06'
```

From that you see that `javax.crypto` also adds PKCS#5 padding, which you need to remove by yourself. That is trivial to do though.

However, the **real** solution to your problem is to do Java encryption in a better way. The Python code will be greatly simplified.

Comment: +1 nice job figuring this out. I spent a while trying to figure out how to convert the negative hex value to the same byte array as BigInteger. Agreed that Java code is a terrible way to print cipher text

Comment: @jterrace If you accept this answer, please click the big white "V" on the left.

Answer (score 0):

This helps me

```
private byte[] encrypt(String key, String plainText) throws GeneralSecurityException {

    SecretKey secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), ALGORITM);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITM);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret_key);

    return cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
}
```

hope this will be useful for you, more http://dexxtr.com/post/57145943236/blowfish-encrypt-and-decrypt-in-java-android