# convert negative values to bytearray

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm testing serial communication with Python so I need to convert hex strings into bytearrays.
But now I'm experiencing problems in representing negative values into hex notation.
Let's say, for example, that I want to convert the hex 16 (decimal 100) into a bytearray; I would use:

```
myvalue = bytearray.fromhex("16")
```

But if I try to convert -100

```
myvalue = bytearray.fromhex("-16")
```

I get a **ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 0**

Concretely, I have to control a motor rotation via usb using serial API. According to documentation, I can specify angle in a range between -32768 and 32767 using 2byte signed value.

So, what should I do?

Comment: There is no "-" symbol in hexadecimal, negative values are just "represented". [Read this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: This answer will help you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822956/how-to-convert-negative-integer-value-to-hex-in-python). It shows how to convert a negative decimal number to a hexadecimal representation. Once you can do that, you simply pass the result as a string to `bytearray.fromhex`.

Comment: Hex 16 isn't decimal 100 at all. It's `1*16**1+6*16**0=22`. In addition, bytearray uses unsigned bytes and has no concept of negative numbers. You may want to look into the struct or array modules. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have to control gimbal rotation via usb; according to documentation, I can specifìy both positive and negative values to set angle radius

Answer (score 2):

When you use `bytearray.fromhex("16")` you are using hex notation to describe the bit pattern you want. In a bit pattern, what we call *sign* is purely conventional. So the correct representation rather depends on whether the receiving process is expecting signed bytes (which can represent the numbers -128 to 127). If it is, then it will probably be expecting a two's-complement representation. The recipe for two's complement is "flip the bits and add 1". So, to represent -1, you start with binary `0000 0001`, flip the bits to get `1111 1110` and add 1 to get `1111 1111` (`0xFF`). Likewise, to represent -100, you start with binary `0110 0100` (`0x64`, decimal 100) , flip the bits to get `1001 1011` and add 1 to get `1001 1100` (`0x9C`).

As you can see, I have an issue with your equating `0x16` with decimal 100. In my book, `0x16` is decimal 22: `0x64` is decimal 100. As shown above, the two's complement of `0x64` is `0x9C`.  To get there from `-100` do this:

```
>>> bytearray([256-100])
bytearray(b'\x9c')
```

That is easier in Python than flipping the bits and adding 1.

To represent a 2-byte negative number, you need to do something analogous. To get two's complement of a 7-bit integer (up to 127), you subtract from 256. To get two's complement of a 15-bit integer (up to 32,767) subtract from 65,536 (*not* 32,767).

To express a negative angle of 10,000: do this 65,536 - 10,000 = 55,536. The bit pattern for that is `0xD8F0`, which is `bytearray([0xd8, 0xf0])`.

As with negative bytes, it is up to the receiver whether it is going to interpret that bit pattern as 55,536 or as -10,000. The equipment you are talking to expects a signed 16-bit integer (range -32768..32767), so it can be relied on to interpret the bit pattern `0xD8F0` as -10,000 and not 55,536. There is no collision of values because 55,536 is out of the allowed range.

Comment: Presence or absence of sign doesn't actually have to do with radix, and Python's literals don't actually include sign (it's the unary negation operator). Two's complement uses modulo arithmetic to represent a negative range within a specific size. It may be more appropriate to use a type that has a sign representation (like `array.array('b', [-100])` or `struct.pack('b', -100)`).

Comment: So, according to your example, 156 and -100 have the same hex value... am I right?

Comment: Yes, in the sense that an unsigned byte representing 156 has the same bit pattern as a signed byte representing -100. Just as a signed 16-bit integer representing -1 has the same bit pattern (`0xFFFF`) as an unsigned 16-bit integer representing 65535. In each case it's up to the receiving process to determine which way it is going to interpret what it gets.

Comment: Concretely, I have to control a motor rotation via usb using serial API.
According to documentation, I can specify angle in a range between -32768 and 32767 using 2byte signed value.

So, if I want to specify a negative angle - let's say -10000 - I should use `bytearray([32767 -10000])`...

But it would be the same as specifying a positive angle of 22767! 
What am I missing?

Comment: What you are missing is that you don't do 32767 - 10000, you do 65536 - 10000. See edited answer for more details.